# Sharing the Fast Healing ability with an Animal Companion

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, animal-companions

Does the animal companion's Share Spells feature allow a druid/ranger who has fast healing to share it with their animal companion?

Comment: What is "Fast Heal"?

Comment: Is this for a druid? If so, you can [edit] your question to link to the druid's Share Spells ability, to the Fast Heal SRD entry (or book & page, if it's not in the SRD), add the [[tag:druid]] tag (and the [[tag:spells]][[tag:animal-companions]] tags), and we can get this unheld and ready for answering. If it's not a druid, please edit with the necessary information.

Comment: Yes for a Druid or Hunter that has Fast Healing and an animal companion. Do they share it Healing properties with spell share?

Comment: Thank you. Please edit your question. It would be useful practice for writing complete & clear questions that don't look like they were written in a hurry.

Answer (score 5):

#### No, fast healing is not shared with animal companions.

From the PFSRD, on [Share Spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Druid/animal-companions/#TOC-Share-Spells-Ex-) (*emphasis mine*):

> The druid may cast a spell with a target of “You” on her animal companion (as a touch range spell) instead of on herself. A druid may cast spells on her animal companion even if the spells normally do not affect creatures of the companion’s type (animal). Spells cast in this way must come from a class that grants an animal companion. *This ability does not allow the animal to share abilities that are not spells, even if they function like spells.*

Share Spells **only** works for *spells* (not spell-like abilities or anything else) that 1) have a range of "You"/"Self"/"Personal" (i.e. spells that can normally only target the caster), and 2) come from a class that grants an animal companion.

If you're getting fast healing from a self-only druid/hunter/ranger spell, then you can also cast that spell on your companion. If you have fast healing from **any other source** then you cannot give it to or share it with your animal companion via Share Spells.